# Navbar isn't clickable in just one section of site

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar

I want the navbar to remain in a fixed position. It works fine but the links aren't clickable in my showcase section. As soon as you scroll down it becomes clickable again. I need help understanding why this is happening

```
 <nav id="nav-bar">
      <h2 class="logo">
      <span class="txt-primary"><i class="far fa-moon"></i></span> | MMM
    </h2>
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#service">Services</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#videos">Videos</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
#nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(60,3,56,0.8);
  color: #dbd8e5;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.4rem;
}

#nav-bar ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#nav-bar ul li a {
  padding: 0.55rem;
  color: #7c72a0;
}
#nav-bar ul li a:hover {
  background: #5f0d45;
  color: #dbd8e5;
  padding: 0.75rem;
}
```

Comment: probably a stacking issue.... have you tried setting a high `z-index`? Something higher than your "showcase section", but you can try like `z-index: 99999;` on the `#nav-bar` just for testing

Comment: consider answering the question @zgood

Answer (score 1):

Add a `z-index` to your `#nav-bar` to stack it higher than the "showcase section".

`z-index: 99999;`

Any element that has a `position` value other than the default of `static` can be stacked on the z-axis (your nav is `position: fixed;`). Higher numbers are on top.

You can set a very high meaningless value like 99999, but I recommend giving it a number that makes sense and you can manage. Find out the `z-index` of the "showcase section" and set it higher than that. If no `z-index` is set, than a simple `z-index: 1;` could work (but sense its a nav a higher number would be better).

If you use sass or less you can keep track easier by setting variables for your sites `z-index`'s.

Also, read about [the stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), because it gets more complicated than just setting higher numbers.

Good luck!